# Using punjabi character in my android application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read character from one of the URL : http://www.searchgurbani.com/hukum/sis_ganj

using the below code :

```
       String htmltext=null;
       String inputLine;

        URL urlinstance = new URL(url);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(urlinstance.openStream()));

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            htmltext+=inputLine;
        in.close();

        htmltext = htmltext.getBytes("UTF-8").toString();
        System.out.println("HTMLTEXT"+htmltext);
```

but when I am trying to read it I am unable to do that.
Can somebody tell me how I can make this work.

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: What errors are you getting? Where is it being throw?

Comment: I am not getting any error just unable to read in desired format...It is reading in some junk format...

Comment: Is it reading it in the same format as when you view the source of your webpage? Does it look something like this: "jb hm hoqy qb qU".

Comment: Yes it reads some things like you mentioned above...Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you can do about it because on that particular website they use a special font that turns the jumbled nonsense into the special characters.

You can see this in action if you view the source of the website and scroll down to where the text should be.

@kenor's answer may also help. Here is how to put that font onto your Android application:

1. Download the font from [here](http://www.sgpc.net/download.asp) and extract the .ttf file into `assets/fonts/myfont.ttf`
2. Create your Typeface as so: `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAssets(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");`
3. Apply that to your TextView by simply doing `myTextView.setTypeface(font);`

Comment: I tried with the above code but its not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

The encoding is UTF-8 indeed, BUT from the css of the site:

```
font-family: WebAkharSlim;
```

which means you have the right characters, but they are showing up wrong because you do not use the right font. You can download the font here: [WebAkharSlim download](http://www.sgpc.net/download.asp) (I don't know a thing about importing fonts into android apps though).